# Using JQuery Slider to Scroll Long Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I tried using a Jquery slider to make scrolling long page easier. My code is

```
    $(document).scroll(function () {
    var doc_top = $(window).scrollTop() ;
    var doc_height = $(window).height();
    $('#slider-mini').val(doc_top / doc_height * 100).slider('refresh');
    });

    $('#slider-mini').on('change',function(){
    var val_mini = document.getElementById("slider-mini").value;
    var doc_height = $(document).height();
    var pos_scroll = val_mini / 100 * doc_height;
    window.scrollTo(0, pos_scroll);
});
```

The complete code here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nurmanx/ee3LavLy/4/)

The problem is when the page scrolls, the page going straight to the bottom and the slider value will be 100.

What i want is when I scroll the page, the slider value follow the scroll position. And when the slider value change, the page scrolling in compliance with the slider value.

I think the two events that I use (onchange () and document.scroll) influence each other.

Any idea how do I resolve this?

Comment: Isn't easier to actually make the user scroll your page as it's supposed to? I mean I like innovations but the ones that make a great UX. I honestly don't find a horizontal handler a good way to scroll the page errm vertically

Answer (score 0):

There are some corrections that we need do.

### HTML

You put `onchange="scrollWin()"` in your input, but you do not have created this function. This generate some errors. You do not need this function, since `$('#slider-mini').on('change'...` do it for you.

### JavaScript

First, you wrote this:

```
var doc_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // It get the WINDOW offset
```

But I think that you wanna this:

```
var doc_height = $(document).height(); // It get the entire DOCUMENT height
```

Then, in the scroll part you forget the parenthesis, so the calculation is wrong and you go to the wrong place when scroll. Look:

```
var pos_scroll = (val_mini / 100) * doc_height; // Correct calculation
```

Also, I notice that the scroll never will get 100, its because the function math is also wrong. I corrected it:

```
$('#slider-mini').val((doc_top) / (doc_height - w_height) * 100).slider('refresh');
```

In the scroll part:

```
var pos_scroll = val_mini / 100 * doc_height;
```

### Final code

```
for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
    $("#my-wrapper").append("<p> Paragraph " + i + "</p>");
}

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var doc_top = $(window).scrollTop() ;
    var doc_height = $(window).height();
    $('#slider-mini').val(doc_top / doc_height * 100).slider('refresh')

});

$('#slider-mini').on('change',function(){
   var val_mini = document.getElementById("slider-mini").value;
    var doc_height = $(document).height();
    var pos_scroll = val_mini / 100 * doc_height;
    window.scrollTo(0, pos_scroll);
});
```

### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4qt92qk/

Comment: +1 Awesome. Its works. Thanks for your complete explanation. In fiddle, onchange="scrollWin()"  doesn't work, so i replaced that with .on('change') but l forgot to delete that.

Comment: You're welcome :) Just mark the correct answer to the question, please.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m4e7nqth/1/)***

To get the right height value you need to calculate `document height - window height`:

```
var $sli = $('#slider-mini'); // Chache your elements, specially the ones
var $doc = $(document);       // you plan to reuse inside a repetitive scroll
var $win = $(window);

$win.on("scroll resize", function () {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop();
    var h = $doc.height() - $(this).height();
    $sli.val(s / h * 100).slider("refresh");
});

$sli.on('change', function(){
    var h = $doc.height() - $win.height();
    window.scrollTo(0, this.value / 100 * h);
});
```

Also as I did above make sure to get/update the value even on `resize`

Comment: Awesome. +1 Thanks for your great answer.  I spent many hours in this code. I don't know if its about the difference about document height and window height. 1000 Thanks